# The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion (sqlserver)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have the following error while I connect to SQL Server 2008 Management Studio with Windows authentication.

"The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion.
Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details."
[image: Start up]

the errorlog file::

```
    2018-01-15 10:43:43.58 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (Intel X86) 
    Mar 29 2009 10:27:29 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (WOW64)

2018-01-15 10:43:43.61 Server      (c) 2005 Microsoft Corporation.
2018-01-15 10:43:43.61 Server      All rights reserved.
2018-01-15 10:43:43.61 Server      Server process ID is 16684.
2018-01-15 10:43:43.61 Server      System Manufacturer: 'Dell Inc.', System Model: 'OptiPlex 5040'.
2018-01-15 10:43:43.61 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.
2018-01-15 10:43:43.61 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.BDMS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG'.
2018-01-15 10:43:43.61 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 3304 at 12/01/2018 3:52:56 PM (local) 12/01/2018 2:52:56 PM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2018-01-15 10:43:43.61 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.BDMS\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
     -e c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.BDMS\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLOG
     -l c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.BDMS\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2018-01-15 10:43:43.66 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-01-15 10:43:43.66 Server      Detected 8 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2018-01-15 10:46:22.60 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2018-01-15 10:46:22.63 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x000000ff Active CPU mask: 0x000000ff. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-01-15 10:49:50.06 Server      SQL Server is terminating because of a system shutdown. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

[image: Services]

Comment: I can't see any connection attempts in that log, which implies your connection attempt isn't reaching the server. Are you trying to connect to a local Instance, or a remote?

Comment: I'm connecting to local system

Comment: In your image the SQL Server status is `Change pending...` Why is that ?

Comment: You did not show us the LAST error log. Those one from your post says that at 10:43:43.61 the service was started and at 10:49:50.06 (6 minutes later) was shut down because of system shutdown. Please show us actual error log